# How do I know which radio checked and which is not with jquery

Tags: jquery, radio-button, jquery-selectors

I am working on php quiz-test script.

I need to know which selected and which is not.

all radios are inside form, they are creating by while.

```
var myRadio = $("#form1 input[type='radio']:checked").val();
alert(myRadio);
```

this just returns 1 value, I have to many radio inside form.

```
<label>

      <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $s_id; ?>" value="<?php echo $cid; ?>"  />
      <?php echo $answer; ?>
</label>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bhtZA/6/)

Comment: Can you set up a jsfiddle demonstrating what you're trying to do? It's difficult to work out what your problem is without an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myRadio = $('input[name=myRadio]');
var checkedValue = myRadio.filter(':checked').val();
```

or

```
$('input[name=radioName]:checked', '#myForm').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like the only identification you have for each one is their -name-, i'm simply logging the radio buttons name attribute then.  By looping through and checking the `prop('checked')`, you can easily see which ones are selected.

```
$('input[type="radio"]').each(function () {
    if ( $(this).prop('checked') === true ) {
        console.log($(this).prop('name'));
    }
});
```

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/bhtZA/1/)

Answer (score 0):

> $('#checkbox').is(':checked')

returns true or false.

[Here you have fiddle link to script](http://jsfiddle.net/LfddZ/1/)